# Javascript Ajax post Method not Working in Laravel 5

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am studing Ajax using JavaScript and want to create an Ajax post method in Laravel 5.4. These are my files...

**Routes**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'],function(){
    Route::post('/ccat','PagesContrpllerController@ccat')->name('ccat');
    Route::resource('/products' , 'ProductController');
});
```

**ProductCategoryController**

```
public function ccat(Request $request){
    return 'hello this is post method';
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function sendfunc(name , level , parent){
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status==200) {
             console.log(this.responseText);
         }
    }

    xhr.open("POST", "ccat", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-formurlencoded");
    xhr.send("fname=Henry&lname=Ford");
}
```

I expect the `'hello this is the post method'` in the console but instead it returns:

> POST http://localhost:8000/admin/product/ccat 404 (Not Found)

What's happening in the console? Even when I change the URL to: http://localhost:8000/admin/ccat` it returns:

> POST http://localhost:8000/admin/ccat 500 (Internal Server Error)

Thanks for any help and ignoring the bad coding.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake that is the missing  `csrf_token` so I add:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

to header of page and get the `csrf_token` in `javascript` and send it to post route by:
`xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN", document.head.querySelector("[name=csrf-token]").content )`;
and its worked. hope be useful for someone else